# Where can I get raw news articles from the last year?

Tags: archive, corpus, article

I'm writing some code that calculates certain statistics about word usages.

Does anyone know where I can find a database of raw news articles from various topics over a period of (say) the last year?  Preferably they would be either in plain text format or XML.  Trying to scrape content from random web sites isn't a good option.

I know going forward I could probably archive them myself.  However, I need to kick start the process with a bunch of existing articles... the more the merrier.

Any other ideas for corpus data-sets that are easily available in simple to parse form would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try the [Internet Archive](http://www.archive.org/).  They have a text section but I don't know if it has news.  You might also be able to use their Wayback machine to pull up news articles from major site using their RSS feeds.

Comment: Thanks, those are nice ideas.

To be honest I was a bit surprised not to have immediately found a raw dump of news articles ready to go just by Googling.  I guess it must be copyright related... but then when did that ever stop anyone.

Comment: Someone else on the programming subreddit also suggested WikiNews.  For what I'm doing, that might actually be more appropriate right now.

Now I just need to figure out how to extract the articles from MediaWiki XML - hopefully shouldn't be too hard.